# How can I export r data frames to Microsoft Access tables?

Tags: r

I am currently using `sqlSave` to export data frame from r into a Microsoft Access database. Are there any other faster or more efficient ways to export r data frames to Microsoft Access tables?

```
   library(parallel)
   num_cores <- detectCores()
   cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
   clusterEvalQ(cl,library(evir))
   set.seed(0)
   system.time(
      x1 <- parLapply(cl, 1:100000,
      function(i) {
          n1 <- rpois(1,4)
          n2<-  rpois(1,7)
      list(data.frame(a=rexp(n1, rate=0.1),a1=rexp(n1, rate=0.6)), 
         data.frame(b=rexp(n2, rate=0.7),b1=rexp(n2, rate=0.6)))

   }
  )
 )

  y1 <- lapply(x1, function(x) x[[1]][["a"]])

  lengths<-function(x) vapply(x,length,1L)

 Create.Matrix<- function(l, s){
   if(is.numeric(l) && length(l) == 0){
      c(0, rep(0, s - 1))
   }else{
      c(l, rep(0, s - length(l)))
  }
 }
 xl <- data.frame(mapply(Create.Matrix,y1, max(lengths(y1))))  
 db <- "Z:/s.accdb"
 con2 <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db)
 sqlSave(con2,xl,"xl",rownames=FALSE,safer=FALSE,fast = TRUE)
```

Comment: What have you googled or researched so far?

Comment: @TimOgilvy found some `BULK INSERT` for MySqL but not much for ms access

Comment: Okay I'm not an r user, what formats does it export?

Comment: You may wish to add more detail to your question, its a bit light on

Comment: @TimOgilvy `sqlSave` exports the r dataframe to ms access just fine, but it's painfully slow.I am just trying to find out if there any alternate methods.

Comment: Can you automate an export in r?  You should be able to program access to check a folder periodically and import a file if it exists.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example, `cl` seems to be missing.

Comment: @MihaTrošt its there now

Comment: I cannot reproduce...`Error in (function (l, s)  : object 'max.size' not found` However, you are trying to save fairly big dataset to Ms Access, that is designed to work with small size datasets. I had similar problems with Access, so I switched to MySql and using `BULK INSERT` command. It worked like a charm and it was fast.